# Create array of symbols with the length of split string

Tags: python

So, I'm making a Hangman game for a beginners coding class and right now I have the function which will return me a random word from a chosen category. Next, I'd like to make an array of ' * ' with each * standing for a letter in the word.

The function I'd like you to help me fix is Array_Juego(palabra_a_jugar)

```
__author__ = 'Rodrigo Cano'
#Modulos

import random

#Variables Globales

intentos = 0
incorrectos = 0
palabras = [(1,"disclosure"),(1,"thenational"),(1,"foals"),(1,"skepta"),(1,"shamir"),(1,"kanye"),
              (1,"fidlar"),(1,"lcdsoundsystem"),(1,"lorde"),(1,"fkatwigs"),(1,"miguel"),(1,"rtj"),
              (1,"boniver"),(1,"strokes"),(2,"vaporwave"),(2,"witchouse"),(2,"shoegaze"),(2,"memerap"),
              (2,"paulblartisoursaviour"),(3,"glockenspiel"),(3,"aesthetic"),(3,"schadenfreude"),
              (3,"bonvivant"),(3,"swag"),(3,"jue")]
palabra_a_jugar = ''
#Funciones

def Definir_Palabra():
    eleccion = int(input("Bienvenido, que categoria quiere usar:"
                     '\n'"1 - Musica que Escuche Mientras Lo Hacia"
                     '\n'"2 - Generos Musicales"
                     '\n'"3 - Palabras Pretenciosas"))
    palabras_escogidas = [i for i in palabras if eleccion in i ]
    palabra_a_jugar = str(palabras_escogidas[random.randint(0,len(palabras_escogidas))].__getitem__(1))
    return palabra_a_jugar


def Array_Juego(palabra_a_jugar):
    Array_Palabra =[]
    for palabra_a_jugar in range(0,len(palabra_a_jugar.split())):
        Array_Palabra.append("_")
    return Array_Palabra

print(Definir_Palabra())
print(Array_Juego(palabra_a_jugar))
```

Comment: `"*" * len(palabra)` will return a string of all "*" characters that is the same length as `palabra`. `list("*" * len(palabra))` will turn that into a list of characters - which is technically what you asked for.

Comment: Or `['*'] * len(palabra)` or `['*' for _ in range(len(palabra))]` for a `list` instead of a string.

Comment: Looking again, I see spaces. Did you want: `[ ' * ' for _ in palabra ]`

Comment: Already tried that approach, didn't work; I think it's taking the word as a single character. Check out how it's implemented `

def Array_Juego(palabra_a_jugar):
    Array_Palabra = list('*' * len(palabra_a_jugar))
    return Array_Palabra`

Comment: ...Did you really do `.__getitem__(1)` instead of `[1]`?

Comment: Guys, first semester CS student with no prior coding knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
for palabra_a_jugar in range(0,len(palabra_a_jugar.split())):
        Array_Palabra.append("_")
```

`palabra_a_jugar` starts out as string.  `split()` returns a list of substrings, broken at a delimiter, which is whitespace by default.  So

```
'palabara a jugar'.split()
```

would return `['palabra', 'a', 'jugar']`

However, you have a single word, presumably.  Say that the value of `palaba_a_jugar` is "pretenciosas".  Then there's no whitespace, so

```
'palabara a jugar'.split()
```

will return

```
['pretenciosas']
```

a one-element list.  This explains the behavior you're seeing.

However, you don't need to go all around the barn like this, and it isn't really worth writing a function for it.  A list of stars the same length as `palabra_a_jugar` is just

```
len(palabra_a_jugar) * ['*']

For example, 4*['*']== ['*','*','*','*']
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much! I was stuck for daaaaaays!